# how to show my image in html through python

Tags: python, url, model-view-controller, bottle, wsgiref

In my views, the code of my index.html is:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <strong><h1>FlowTow</h1></strong>
        <b><h3>POWERED BY BOOTSTRAP</h3></b>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        % for item in result:
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 image">

            <p class="username">{{item['user']}}</p>
            <p class="dates">{{item['timestamp']}}</p>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <img src="static/images/{{item['filename']}}" alt="{{item['filename']}}" class="img-responsive imagee">

            <p class="likes">{{ item['likes'] }}Likes</p>

            <form action="/like" method="post" class="like_form">
                <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="{{item['filename']}}">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Like">
            </form>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        % end

    </div>

</div>
```

But the index does not show the image. The image is stored in my file "static/images". When I check the element of the website, the address of the image is shown like:

```
<img src="static/images/cycling.jpg" alt="cycling.jpg" class="img-responsive imagee">
```

I am sure the url of the image is correct. Can someone tell me why the image is not shown?

Comment: What is your web framework (django, flask, ...) ? Do you have a web server (nginx, apache ...) in front ?

Comment: Can you view the image in your browser?

Comment: My framework is bottle, server is WSGIREF. @Cyrbil

Comment: I can't @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: Then that would be your problem, and none of the above code has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#routing-static-files) shows how to serve static file:
Simply create a route for it in your app and use [`static_file()`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#static-files) function

```
from bottle import static_file
@route('/static/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root='/path/to/your/static/files')
```